# React - Best practice with state in form components?

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs

I'm trying to get my head around best practice regarding state in react components. I started creating a form by writing a TextField component as follows

```
var TextField = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        const {value, title, placeholder} = this.props;
        return (<div>
            {title}
            <input type="text"
                value={value}
                placeholder={placeholder}
                onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </div>);
    },

    handleChange (evt){
        this.props.onChange(evt.target.value);
    }
});
```

This is a controlled component. So the parent container has to pass a value in for the input in via props and change that value when there is a change. It seems like this is the usual approach.

My problem comes when I want to create a numeric field. For this example assume that my numeric field will allow non numeric characters to be input (the field just won't validate). I don't like the idea of having the validation of that field within the parent so this is what I wrote

```
var NumericField = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function(){
        return{
            value : ""
        }
    },

    componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
        if(this.validate(nextProps.value)){
            this.setState({value:nextProps.value});
        }
    },

    validate : function(input) {
        return !isNaN(input);
    },

    render: function() {
        const {value} = this.state;
        const {title} = this.props;
        return (<div>
            {title}
            <input type="text"
                value={value}
                onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </div>);
    },

    handleChange (evt){
        this.setState({value:evt.target.value});
        if(this.validate(evt.target.value)){
            this.props.onChange(evt.target.value);
        }
    }
});
```

This allows the parent to set the value and update it via the "value" prop, but the "onChange" prop will only trigger when the content is valid. It feels to me like I've used a different pattern for each, and that's not good. Not sure if that's a valid feeling?

I suppose I just wanted to ask if my approach to the numeric field seems reasonable or if there is a better pattern to follow?

Just in case someone wants to know why I want a numeric field to work this way, I don't, it's just a simplified example. A more valid example would be a text area for json, that only called onChange when the content was valid json.

Appreciate any feedback

Answer (score 2):

Setting state by passing in props is generally frowned upon.
Props should be immutable (like your NumericField component's title)
If you want to set an initial value it should come from the controller or store the parent component is getting it from, eg.

```js
getInitialState() {
  return({
    value: FormDataStore.getInitialNumericFieldValue()
  });
}
```

After that, any changes to the value should be handled by the NumericField component. If you need to validate do so before setting the new state, eg.

```js
handleChange(evt) {
  if (this.validate(evt.target.value)){
    this.setState({
      value: evt.target.value
    });
    /* You can also pass the new validated value
       up to the parent component to hold on to
       till you're ready to process the form*/
    this.props.onChange(evt.target.value);
  }
}
```

Your state will now only ever hold (and subsequently the parent component will only ever receive) the last validated value so you could even display valid/invalid message if this.state.value === input, but that's extra

Incidentally, your TextField component should also follow this pattern. Passing a changed value up to the parent just to have it passed down again as a prop defeats the purpose of having a child component. In that case I would have the JSX (and any  validation process) all in the parent component instead of abstracting a child. Unless the child component could be re-used. But then I'd still let the child handle its own state.

Comment: Thanks X-Fix, that all makes sense and I see that your right regarding the TextField purpose being a bit pointless. I want my form components to update if the state of the entire form changes up the tree though. I've been looking around and found this library for form building http://mozilla-services.github.io/react-jsonschema-form/, notice how the formdata can be changed within the form and outside of the form. Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: @Ben Disclaimer: I'm more familiar with using Flux with React (one-way data flow). My approach would be to have the data saved in the (eg.) FormDataStore, then the handleChange function from the first component would save changes (post successful validation) straight to the store. With Flux you use action creators and a dispatcher for this see [link](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html) . The store then emits a 'change' event, the second component (outside the form) fetches the updated value and changes to reflect this, and vice versa from out- to in-side the form

Comment: @Ben I should also mention that with this approach, the child components no longer store/manipulate a state object and can have their field values set by props passed in by the parent. The parent then has its data updated when the store emits a 'change' event

Comment: Thanks, that sounds reasonable. I looked at flux and thought it might help provide a better solution. I think that's the direction I'll explore next, just wanted to get my basic knowledge of React sorted first. Really appreciate your help, thanks.